# For loop prints two $values instead of one

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, loops, for-loop

I've a problem with bash array loop.

the following code instead of printing each value separately, joins two values and prints them as if they are one.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a array=( 'sf052' 'to060' 'pw' 'qb099' 'pw22' 'wp039' 'wx12' 'wx11' )
for i in "${array[@]}"; do
    echo $i
done
```

Output:

```
sf052
to060
pw
qb099 pw22
wp039 wx12
wx11
```

Expected output:

```
sf052
to060
pw
qb099
pw22
wp039
wx12
wx11
```

Running `bash --version` gives

```
GNU bash, version 4.2.45(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

and `uname -a`:

```
Linux server1 3.11.0-12-generic #19-Ubuntu SMP
Wed Oct 9 16:20:46 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Works as expected for me - maybe you have some other problem?

Comment: What's your bash version?

Comment: I'm using bash 3.2 on OS X: `GNU bash, version 3.2.51(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin13)`

Comment: Well I'm using the latest maybe that's where the problem.

Comment: works for me in bash 4.2.25 - Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: there must be something else going on with your environment. If you put that snippet in a file and invoke it with `bash filename`, what happens?

Comment: Post a complete script that reproduces the problem. (A complete script starts with `#!/bin/bash` and is executed by typing `/path/to/script`.)

Comment: @glennjackman that's how i did it in the first place

Comment: Works for me under bash 4.2.37(1).  (I would try 4.2.45 if I had it.)

Comment: tried on another machine with `4.2.45(1)` and it worked. so it's really should be related to the system somehow.

Comment: What do you get if you run it with `env -i bash yourscript` on your original system?

Comment: I'm guessing you had a typo error. You intended to have `'sf052' 'to060' 'pw' 'qb099' 'pw22' 'wp039' 'wx12' 'wx11'` but you may have typed `'sf052' 'to060' 'pw' 'qb099 pw22' 'wp039 wx12' 'wx11'`

Comment: while your question looks clean, if you've created the script in a Windows environment and have moved it to a Linux environment, then try `dos2unix scriptFile`. Good luck.

Comment: Crossposted: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2014-01/msg00010.html

Comment: Run `hexdump -C <your_file>` and make sure those spaces between the array elements are really `20`s.

Answer (score 1):

The separator between `qb099` and `pw22` should be the space character.
The same with `wp039` and `wx12`.
To validate that use the [octal dump](http://www.unix.com/man-page/OpenSolaris/1/od) utility.

For me the output is as expected:

```
0000000   #   !   /   b   i   n   /   b   a   s   h  \n  \n   d   e   c
0000020   l   a   r   e       -   a       a   r   r   a   y   =   (
0000040   '   s   f   0   5   2   '       '   t   o   0   6   0   '
0000060   '   p   w   '       '   q   b   0   9   9   '       '   p   w
0000100   2   2   '       '   w   p   0   3   9   '       '   w   x   1
0000120   2   '       '   w   x   1   1   '       )  \n   f   o   r
0000140   i       i   n       "   $   {   a   r   r   a   y   [   @   ]
0000160   }   "   ;       d   o  \n                   e   c   h   o
0000200   $   i  \n   d   o   n   e  \n
```

Probably for most of us the code worked, because we copied it from here.
However if you copy-paste from Windows (such as Word document) sometimes special characters come in place, that can't be seen visually.